# Média da nota dos alunos e a soma das médias

Tags: javascript, array

Galera, como sou novo em JS, queria uma ajudinha de vocês.

Bom, vamos a alguns passos:

1. Tenho essa constante que irá retornar um array de objetos

```
    const alunos = [
      {
        nome: 'aluno1',
        notas: [9, 8.5, 10]
      },
      {
        nome: 'aluno2',
        notas: [6.5, 7.5, 6]
      },
      {
        nome: 'aluno3',
        notas: [3, 2, 4.5]
      }
    ];
```

2. Quero calcular a média das notas, mostradas na variável do objeto "notas".
3. E, por fim, somar as médias dos alunos.

Como posso fazer essa instrução?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá  masterofdefeats seja bem vindo ao STO em PT, bom, você poderia tentar algo do tipo:

```
    alunos.map(aluno => {
      aluno.media = aluno.notas.reduce((t, n) => t + n, 0)/aluno.notas.length
      return aluno
    })
```

Por fim, para somar as médias dos alunos, pode usar algo como:

```
let somaMedia = alunos.map(e => e.media).reduce((t, n) => t + n, 0)
```